# Which is correct? I'm not a Trump or I'm not Trump?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I'm not sure what to use.

The context is I'm telling that I don't have power like he. So, showing that I'm powerless, I say...

> I can't do that. I'm not (a) Trump.

I think it is with an 'a' because you are describing Trump with a special quality that I don't have! However, not sure and that's why asked!

Comment: Maybe, *I can't do that. I'm not Trump.* is clear enough?

Comment: Consider also: *I'm no Trump!*

Comment: Note that "a Trump" often means a member of the Trump family. "Of course Ivanka said that—she's a Trump."

Answer (score 2):

Both are acceptable. Use of the article *a* makes it generic, in the sense of like the *type* of person that Trump is.
The implication is you are talking about Trump's behavior.

Without the article, it means specifically like the *person* named Trump. This *could* be addressing Trump's behavior, or *in context*, it might be about Trump's abilities.

Concerning behavior:

> That's a terrible thing to do! I cant do that, I'm not a Trump.

Concerning abilities:

> Make a treaty with a foreign nation? I can't do that, I'm not Trump.

The distinction is subtle, and the first example would also be acceptable without the article, though the second one, adding an article, would be better as:

> Make a treaty with a foreign nation? I can't do that, I'm not the president.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m not a Trump.

> I’m not Trump.

This sentence literally tells you in a straightforward manner that you  are not Trump, and do not have the choice the upright decisions of the president like Trump.

> I can’t make decisions, I’m not Trump!

This implies that you are not the president & you cannot make any decisions for the country.

(P.S. At this period of time I’m writing this answer, the 2020-2021 US elections are over and Biden is president. When you wrote this question (2018), Trump was president and I’ll assume in the sentences above that Trump is considered as president. )

Comment: No, a Trump supporter would be called "Trumper" or "Trumpist", among other more colorful things.

Comment: @EddieKal sorry to ask, so is I’m not a Trump a grammatical sentence?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly grammatical.